# How to update homescreen widget with cursor.movetonext() in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I created a widget in my android app. I connect to database and get some column values. I want this widget to be updated every 10 seconds and get next values from my database.
I wanted to do it using `cursor.movetonext()` but I'm not sure how to use it here.

This is my java class for widget:

```
public class DataAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private String dataP;
    private String dataE;
    private dataRepo dataRepo;
    private Cursor cursor;


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.data_app_widget);
            dataRepo = new dataRepo(context.getApplicationContext());

                cursor = dataRepo.getallData();
                dataP = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data_P.KEY_P_NAME));
                dataE = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data_E.KEY_E_NAME));
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_p, dataP);
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_e, dataE);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }

}
```

This is my widget info xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/data_app_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/data_app_widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="180dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/data_appwidget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen"></appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem.

I created new preference , and then using SharedPreference I stored count number.

Then, everytime widget is updated I get my number from SharedPreference and I use `cursor.move(mynumber)`, after this I set mynumber value +1 and store it again.